# Meteor spacebars property key not working

Tags: meteor, spacebars, meteor-helper

I'm trying to print a JSON API response using templates in Meteor. For testing purposes I have manually entered it into a:

```
Template.body.helpers({
entries: [
    {
        "item_link": "http://www.blocket.se/ostergotland/Tannefors_62513807.htm?ca=14&w=1",
        "item_link/_text": "Tannefors"
    },
    {
        "item_link": "http://www.blocket.se/ostergotland/Moblerad_1_a_i_Duvkullen_62466395.htm?ca=14&w=1",
        "item_link/_text": "Möblerad 1:a i Duvkullen"
    }
]}
```

The problem is the "item_link/_text" key, which doesn't work using Meteors template engine.

```
<body>
   {{#each entries}}
       {{> entry}}
  {{/each}}
</body>

<template name="entry"> 
    <h2>{{item_link/_text}}</h2>     
    {{item_link}}     
</template>
```

The "item_link" property works fine, but "item_link/_text" does not work, I guess it's because of the frontslash. I have tried things like escape it with "\\", but no luck.

**Running example http://meteorpad.com/pad/e4D37M5ipdXcgmABG/Special%20character%20fail**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [spacebars readme](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/spacebars/README.md#identifiers-and-paths), you can simply wrap it in square brackets like this:

```
<h2>{{ [item_link/_text] }}</h2>
```

Here's [a working copy of your example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/S9mjQcFFa4x45MraY/Copy%20of%20Special%20character%20fail).

Comment: Kriegslustig's answer works but it's better practice to follow the regular standards for variable naming. Which means not having a "/" in the name of your variable.

Comment: @SirCharlesWatson Definitely agree, but I think his problem is, that the key is coming from some third party API. So he can't influence it.

Comment: Ahh. Missed that part. Well in that case... Carry on... Haha

Comment: Thanks alot! And no, I can't change the property name.. which of course would have been the best solution.